# Xamarin Forms - Saving Files (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal does not work)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

i'm having a small issue with Xamarin.Forms

This works -

```
    Java.IO.File path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim);

            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(path.AbsolutePath, "dsdsd.txt"), false))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("yoyoyoyoy");
                sw.Close();
            }
```

However , using the XF Folder options as in "Working With Files" Guide ..The file is not created

```
    var fPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    string filePath = Path.Combine(fpath, "dsdsd.txt");

            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath, false))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("yoyoyoyoy");
                sw.Close();
            }
```

Any idea what is causing this issue ?

I would prefer to use my App folder instead of a public one .

I did a test on the paths :

With Xamarin Environment :

```
/data/data/TestApp.Droid/files/dsdsd.txt  (Does not work)
```

With Android Path :

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/dsdsd.txt  (works)
```

---

My Actual app Folder path (When i browse using pc) :

```
\Phone\Android\data\TestApp.Droid\files
```

Comment: Did you also updated your manifest with the required permissions?

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue, you can use DDMS to check the file if it is exist.